# Use of virtual in a class hieracrhy when a base class uses it

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I'm not understanding an inheritance example from Stroustrup's *A Tour of C++*, pages 43 and 44.  I've reproduced a minimal example that demonstrates my confusion:

```
#include <iostream>

class Shape {
public:
    virtual void draw() const = 0;
    virtual ~Shape() {};
};

class Circle : public Shape {
public:
    Circle(int p, int rr) : x{p}, r{rr} {}
    void draw() const { std::cout << "In Circle::draw()" << std::endl; }
private:
    int x;
    int r;
};

class Smiley : public Circle {
public:
    Smiley(int p, int r): Circle{p,r}, mouth(nullptr) {}
    ~Smiley() { delete mouth; }
    void draw() const { std::cout << "In Smiley::draw()" << std::endl; }

private:
    Shape* mouth;
};

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Circle *smiley;
    smiley = new Smiley(3, 4);
    smiley->draw();

    Circle *circle;
    circle = new Circle(3, 4);
    circle->draw();

    return 0;
}
```

What confuses me is that Circle::draw is not virtual.  I saw that and figured this must be a typo.  Since virtual says to look at a derived class for a definition, I didn't think that Smiley's draw would ever be called polymorphically from a base Circle reference.  However, I run the code and get the following output:

```
In Smiley::draw()
In Circle::draw()
```

Please help. How is this possible?  How did Smiley::draw get called from a Circle* pointer when Circle::draw is not virtual?  Is it not necessary to declare derived class functions virtual (such as Circle::draw) for further derived class's functions (such as Smiley::draw) when a base class of the heirarchy is virtual (Shape::draw)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Circle::draw` is in fact virtual! This is because `Shape::draw` is virtual. When overriding a virtual function from a base class, the function is automatically virtual and does not require the keyword. I like to provide the virtual keyword to make it clear it is a virtual function, but it is optional.

In C++11 you can mark overridden functions `override` in order to ensure they are actually overriding a virtual function. This prevents mistakes.

```
void draw() const override
```

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Yes it is.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti It's not overriding a non-virtual function.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti - yes there is, and it's vtable entry will typically point to a function that reports the fact you've called a pure virtual function which has no implementation.

Comment: Oh damn I didn't see the `Shape` base class with `virtual void draw()!` my bad!!! (edited just to undownvote)

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is that draw remains virtual even if it is not specified, as long as the first declaration of draw (at top of the class hierarchy) is declared virtual.